# mvc3 https & http

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am converting an asp.net application into mvc3. Lets say I have a sign in page that requires https and every other page only needs http how can I redirect the signin to https and keep all the other pages on http?

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`RequireHttpsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute.aspx) class may be what you want.

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult SignIn() {
   return View();
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that after they sign in, per your question, you should redirect them to the next page explicitly using http. This way they aren't stuck on https the entire time.

Comment: @jab hot to redirect to next page explicitly using http? Is it possible with RedirectToAction()?

Answer (score 4):

I like this solution because:
1. Cause you never have to touch it again in VS. The decorator by itself causes the browser to  render the site in https even in debug.

1. If you implement it into a base controller and have all your controllers inherit from that controller, you know there is no slipping in the back do "So to speak".

   ```
   #if !DEBUG
   #define RELEASE
   #endif namespace ProjectName.UI.Controllers {
       using System.Web.Mvc;
       #if RELEASE
           [RequireHttps]
       #endif
       public abstract partial class ProjectNameBaseController : Controller
       {
       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

A co-worker of mine and I looked at this and believe we found a good solution.  Here is what we came up with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class HttpsRequiredAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check to see if we're secure
        string requirestr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RequireHttps"];
        bool require;
        if (bool.TryParse(requirestr, out require) && require)
            base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
    }       

}
```

This works by extending the RequireHttpsAttribute, and can be applied to a class or method, as indicated by the AttributeTargets.  We then overrode the virtual function in RequireHttpsAttribute.  What the method does is check the Web.config file for a key called "RequireHttps".  If it cannot find it, or it's an invalid bool value (which is what the bool.tryparse checks), then it does not require Https.  If it finds the value as true, then it requires HTTPS.

If you use this extension, you'll need to add a key in your Web.config called "RequireHttps," like so:
`<add key="RequireHttps" value="true"/>`
You can then turn off the requirement for Https by changing this variable for when you're debugging, or by changing your Web.config file to have the requirement wherever your site is deployed.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is that after log in all your requests are going to be https even if you don't want it